# Elasticsearch upgrade doc_values enabled?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I've recently upgraded my Elastic cluster from 1.7.5 to 2.1.2.

I've read than in version 2+ Doc Values are enabled by default but I am wondering if this applies to the upgrade I have performed? I have checked my _mapping and _settings against the cluster but can't see any references to doc values.

If my understanding of how doc values work is correct, I was hoping this would go some way towards alleviating memory consumption issues on the cluster.

Comment: Have you performed [an upgrade](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/indices-upgrade.html) of your old indices after the upgrade so that the old indices get migrated to the new Lucene format? Upgrading your cluster from 1.7 to 2.1 won't change the mapping of your old indices to use doc values. All new indices you will create will have doc values enabled by default, though, but your old indices need to be upgraded first.

Comment: No, thank you, I wasn't aware of the upgrade API. Are you saying the upgrade will enable doc_values in the old indices or should I re-index into new indexes? I'd like to avoid re-indexing if possible as I have 2 billion+ docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your cluster upgrade to 2.1.2, you should [perform an index upgrade](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/indices-upgrade.html) of your old indices so that they get migrated to the new Lucene format.

All the new indices you will create in 2.1.2 will have doc values enabled by default, so there's nothing special to be done there.

However, all your old indices need to be upgraded first in order to leverage the Lucene format used in ES 2.1.2 . After that index upgrade, all your old indices will start using doc values for all existing fields (except analyzed strings of course), **BUT** all the already indexed data will not be back-filled into doc values files. For that, you'll need to reindex your data in order to use  doc values for your existing data. All the new data coming into your old upgraded indices will be using doc values, though.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! I can now move fwd with this.